# How to access HTTPS on development server

Tags: django, ssl-certificate, django-extensions

I have a Django project. I tried to run develop SSL server by

```sh
python manage.py runserver_plus --cert-file cert.crt
```

But anytime I get error Site doesn't reach. How I can fix it? I have mapped my `hosts.ics` file, tried also a `sslserver`, but nothing is working.